# Easiest way to find a vector in a span

Tags: vector-spaces

So $V=\text{span}\{v_1, v_2\}$ where $v_1 = (1, 1, -1)$ and $v_2 = (1, -1, 2)$

I have been given four different vectors and must find which vectors are in $V$. What is the most efficient way to do this? The vectors I have been given are as follows:

- $x_1 = (1,0,-1)$
- $x_2 = (0,2,5)$
- $x_3 = (0,2,-3)$
- $x_4 = (9,31,-44)$

Comment: It may not be the most effective way, but solving the equation $x_i = \alpha v_1 + \beta v_2$ clearly brings to you an end ;-)

Comment: Also you have to specify over which field this vector space is spanned!

Comment: via Ax=b where b is the vector you want to check that is in V (you havent given this) or not, and the columns of A is the basis/vectors in the span set given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that if $(x,y,z) = a(1,1,-1)+b(1,-1,2) = (a+b, a-b, -a+2b)$ then $x=3y+2z$.

Answer (score 0):

It may be effective to just try to find a linear combination for the first component and then check whether the other components can be spanned by this to. So you will notice that just $x_3 \in V$:

For example my thoughts to check $x_2$:

$0 = 1 - 1$, so $\alpha = 1$ and $\beta = -1$. For the second component you have with those values $2 = 1 - (-1)$ which is true. But the third component gives $-1 - 2 = -3 \neq 5$. So this vector is not in $V$.